# What "title" is Jasmine referring to?

Tags: aladdin, aladdin-2019

In *Aladdin (2019)*, Prince Anders about to marry Jasmine:

> Prince Anders: So, why did no one tell me of your beauty?
>
> Jasmine: No one mentioned yours, either.
>
> Prince Anders: Oh! Thank you. They say that in Skanland. It's very,
>   very amusing.
>
> Jasmine: Is it?
>
> Prince Anders: Yeah.
>
> Jasmine: We have **the same title**, yet are never described the same way.

What "title" is Jasmine referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, she's referring to the title of "princess". As the daughter of the Sultan, Jasmine is the princess of Agrabah, just as Anders is the prince of Skanland. I haven't seen the 2019 version, so I'm unsure if she's ever explicitly referred to as a princess in it, but in the original 1992 film she is referred to as "Princess Jasmine" on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 2):

The Ttile is a reference to their individual statuses as heir to their thrones (princes and prince). 
The "Never described in the same way" is a nod to the fact that a prince is often seen as the future ruler while the princess is often seen as a walking womb to birth the future ruler.

Comment: She's not the heir to the throne. That's why she's grumpy

Comment: @Valorum she is the crown princess, making her the legitimate heir, the problem is that because she is a woman it is nothing more then a title and that her future husband will be the one holding power not her.